# Return tuple room database android

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am trying to return a tuple from a query on a room database but each time null is returned.

My entity class has an embedded object which contains the 4 properties I want to return in my tuple.

I have tried both defining the 4 properties in the tuple class and just defining embedded object in the tuple class but no luck

I have other queries working perfect returning tuples but the properties they return are defined at the class level of the entity class, not in embedded objects

Anyone have any ideas on how I can return a select number of properties from the embedded object using a tuple or another way?

Comment: can you show some code? For example, your tuple class and your type converter.

Comment: @LieForBananas  I’ll post up some code as soon as I get back to the laptop, however I do not have a type converter as a type converter is not needed with embedded objects

Comment: I misunderstood then. Ok then post the code when you can.

Comment: @LieForBananas apologies for not updating this sooner, but I figured out the issue.....I had an error in the parameters I was passing into the query

Comment: No problem I understand, thanks a lot for getting back here :) make sure to answer your question if it can help anyone :)